# How to publish iPhone app and create binary file

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, app-store

I want to submit new version of app which was first uploaded by  my friend. now i want to update it on app store.

I am following [this](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/submitting-iphone-apps-to-the-apple-app-store-a-step-by-step-guide/) tutorial link for uploading app on app-store

But whenever i am download provisional certificate for distribution and i click on it, it says valid signing identity not found. What i am doing wrong in it. 
I have create certificate from key chain access and upload it to Development under Certificates and downloaded it . and then created my APP id and then created provisional certificate and downloaded it and clicked on it, then it opened in xCODE ( valid signing identity not found.

Comment: See [Apple Technical Note TN2294](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2294/_index.html).

Comment: You need the private key of your friend installed in your keychain.

Comment: please check [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/8045/how-to-submit-your-app-to-apple-from-no-account-to-app-store-part-2)

Comment: @RDC, do i have to revoke distribution certificate and upload a new certificate in distribution section and download it again? or use previous one make by my friend?

Comment: @Zohaib Just go to developer profile and download all the certificates from there. NOTE: Don't forget to add .CSR file from which all certificates have been created. Without adding same .CSR file, developer profile certificates will not work. OTHERWISE JUST revoke all the certificates to get rid of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the user to whom the dev account belongs has the ability to submit apps to the app store.  It uses their certificate to do the submission.  If you want to submit to the store you'll need your friend to install their certificate on your computer.  You can then use that to do the submission.  Just be prepared to bug your friend whenever their cert expires to repeat the process.

Comment: i am using my friends account for submiting app